# Rebuilding a wxWidgets installation with vcpkg and a modified setup.h configuration file

Tags: windows, installation, wxwidgets, vcpkg

The version of setup.h that vcpkg uses to build wxWidgets (x64-windows) has some values I want to change. I want to make these changes and have the library rebuilt using my values.

I can't find a way to get vcpkg to rebuild the package. I can only 'remove' it and 'install' it. The 'remove' takes my changed setup.h with it, and the 'install' installs Microsoft's defaults (... and these ARE Microsoft's defaults; they are different to the defaults you get if you download the source and compile it yourself...)

Anybody know how to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

@GeoffreyArmstrong,

Why not download the source code from [www.wxwidgets.org](http://www.wxwidgets.org), download MSVC Community Edition from Microsoft and build the library yourself with whatever configuration you want?

1. Install MSVC Community 2019.
2. Download and unpack wxWidgets to, i.e. C:\wxWidgets-3.1.4.
3. Start MSVC and open C:\wxWidgets-3.1.4\build\msw\wx_vc16.sln (latest one available).
4. Open C:\wxWidgets\include\msw\setup.h and make those modifications.
5. In MSVC select "Build -> Batch Build...", click "Select All", then click "Build"
6. Go drink some coffee.
7. When the build finishes, open C:\wxWidgets-3.1.4\samples\minimal\minimal_vcN.sln
8. Build it and run it.

What could be simpler?

Thank you

Comment: I can certainly do that, I've done that up until I discovered vcpkg. But using vcpkg is so convenient because most of my dependancies like SSL and Boost come on vcpkg, and that makes things so much easier when it comes time to move to a new PC. And that happens more than I would like.

Comment: @GeoffreyArmstrong, this is a beauty of the package manager - once something is packaged you can't re-packaged it. That's why you build it yourself and enjoy it.

Comment: @Igor In step 4, I didn't find that specific path but rather "\wxWidgets-3.1.4\include\wx\msw\setup.h" and "\wxWidgets-3.1.4\include\msvc\wx\setup.h". Are either of these the same as you the setup.h you are referencing?

Comment: @viracocha, whats your comment about?

Comment: @Igor Actually please disregard my comment; I found my answer and should have researched a bit more before deciding to potentially take up your time. I apologize.

Comment: @viracocha, that's ok. I was just confused because you comment was not about the question the OP was asking.